# How can I find has the entered time expired? ReactJS+Spring project

Tags: java, mysql, reactjs, spring, hibernate

I'm doing an auction project. I want to take a time like 1 day, 1 week or 12 hours from the user and check the end of it. . But how can I compare the time the user entered with the current time and find out that the time has expired and I don't know if I should do this in react or spring.

Let's say starting time is : 04/06/2022-00:00:00
End time is : 04/06/2022-12:00:00
I would like to invalid the auction when starting time and end time equal.

Auction class will be like this.

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Auction {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    
    @NotNull
    private String name;
    
    @NotNull
    private String title;
    
    @NotNull
    private String price;
    
    @NotNull
    private Date startDate;
    
    @NotNull
    private Date endDate;
    
    @NotNull
    private Category category;
    
    @NotNull
    private String sellNowPrice;
    
    private User seller;
    
    private User buyer;
    

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should validate this type of data always in your backend (Spring), because otherwise other people with access to your API can easily bypass this data validation if they are just using the HTTP Request without your frontend. Therefore, you should validate this data in your backend.

Now for the implementation:

```
Date currentDate = new Date();
long diffInMillies = Math.abs(currentDate.getTime() - endDate.getTime());
long diff = TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(diffInMillies, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

If the `diff` is now a negative amount the auction has not reached the end date yet. But if `diff` is a positive number, the auction ended since `diff`-days